# Как правильно достать данные из файла JSON в React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, reactjs

В связи с не знанием React достаточно хорошо, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть [файл](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Sky-shop-Task-React-/blob/main/public/products.json) JSON.
Есть [компоненты](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Sky-shop-Task-React-/tree/main/src/components) React.
[Ссылка](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Sky-shop-Task-React-)  на весь репозиторий.

На данный момент в файле Main.jsx пытаюсь вытянуть данный из JSON файла "products.json" и провести с ними дальнейшие манипуляции (Product.jsx; Products.jsx).

В конечном результате получаю "Nothing found" ( Условие в Products.jsx)

Вопрос - в чём заключается проблема, почему не получается отобразить данные?

**Фото Main.jsx**
[image: main]

**Фото Product.jsx**
[image: product]

**Фото Products.jsx**
[image: products]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я не вижу файла `products.json` в вашем проекте

Comment: Добавьте код текстом вместо скриншотов.

Answer (score 0):

Файл `products.json` ваш код ищет в папке `layout`, а не в папке `public`.

дополнительно, у вас опечатка в слове `response`

ну и целом, подход, мне не понятен

вот мой вариант, переместил ваш products.json в папку layout, добавил import и присвоил в state значение этого импорта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что вывел console.log
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, сделал так-же, работает, а как теперь правильно передать data,чтобы я получил желаемый вывод данных?

Comment: куда передавать data?